# Is there a tool to automate/stress POST calls to my site for testing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing

I would like to stress (not sure this is the right word, but keep reading) the [POST] actions of my controllers. Does a tool exist that would generate many scenarios, like omitting fields, adding some, generating valid and invalid values, injecting attacks, and so on ? Thx

**Update**: I don't want to benchmark/performance test my site. Just **automatically filling/tampering** forms and see what happens

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want the tool to generate the requests automatically and randomly, or do you want it to replay the scenarios that you yourself create?

Comment: right, automatically and randomly.

Answer (score 1):

WebInspect from Spidynamics (HP bought them).

I've used this one in my previous job (I recommended it to my employer at the time) and I was overwhelmed with the amount of info and testing I could do with it.

https://download.spidynamics.com/webinspect/default.htm

Answer (score 1):

Apache JMeter, is more likely to benchmark/stress itself rather than your site. I was recently pointed twards [Faban](http://faban.sunsource.net/) which can be used for very simple and more complex tests and scenarios, its very performant. Also, take a look at [OpenSTA](http://www.opensta.org/) and [WebLoad](http://www.webload.org/) both free and powerful with capabilities to record and replay complex scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) might fit the bill?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [CrossBow Web Stress Tester](http://crossbow.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14770) over at CodePlex?

- supports get and post operations
- you specify the number of threads, requests, waits, and timeouts
- reads a txt file with name/value pairs for posting values

You'd have to download & modify the source if you wanted to generate random data for your Post variables.

Answer (score 0):

Build one yourself by using WebClient with HtmlAgilityPack. Use agilitypack to parse your html and get the form, then just randomly fill the fields and make POSTs